# Executing VBA Script in Excel file by Nodejs package

Tags: node.js, excel, vba

I have some `xlsm` files with VBA script inside and hope that can automatically run VBA script by nodejs code. Is that possible with nodejs?
I have searched for a while but it seems like we only can add VBA script into `xlsx` files, not execute the code.

[File here](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/issues/626)

Any advice is welcome!

Comment: Can you re-write with .Net? That can be run via [edge](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge)?

Comment: @QHarr So basically, I will execute VBA script by .NET and run .NET code inside javascript code by `edge`, right ? Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: No. Write as .Net and run.

Comment: But what if our project requires Nodejs, that's sad

Comment: I mean write vba as .Net and execute from NodeJs

Comment: So, I will write .Net code to handle Excel stuff and execute from `edge`? How can I do that, please give me some detail instructions!